# X.org missing fonts

Tags: xorg, freebsd, x11, fonts

I have a font installed (7x14, part of the xorg-fonts-miscbitmaps package), which I would like to use in my xterm. Problem is, X won't let me.

X seems to pick up the font dir:

```
# grep -A 3 FontPath /var/log/Xorg.0.log
(==) FontPath set to:
/usr/local/lib/X11/fonts/misc/,
/usr/local/lib/X11/fonts/TTF/,
/usr/local/lib/X11/fonts/OTF
```

... but it doesn't show up inside X:

```
# xlsfonts | egrep "[0-9]+x[0-9]"
6x13
```

The `/usr/local/lib/X11/fonts/misc` folder contains a bunch of NxM-*.pcf.gz files, for various values of N and M. Only the 6x13 one seems to be useable, though.

How do I make the rest of the misc-fonts available?

Answer (score 2):

When you install a bitmap font, you need to run [`mkfontdir`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mkfontdir&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE+and+Ports) to register the font in the `fonts.dir` file. (This isn't specific to FreeBSD.) I would expect the package installation script to take care of that, but maybe this package didn't do it.

As a user who has permission to write to `/usr/local/lib/X11/fonts/misc/`, run `mkfontdir /usr/local/lib/X11/fonts/misc/`. Then tell your running X instance to reread the font list with `xset fp rehash`.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Running mkfontdir creates the file fonts.dir, containing a lot of lines, including a bunch of 7x14's. However, xlsfonts still only gives me the 6x13 one.

Comment: `xset fp rehash` was the key point for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions miss the additional step of `xset fp+ /usr/local/lib/X11/fonts/misc/`.  If the `font.dir` file is already there then you can skip the `mkfontdir` command.